# Speed SELECT SQlite Python very unstable

Tags: python, performance, sqlite

I'm using a reasonably large SQLite database (300 - 400 MB) together with a Python 3 program , it has two columns, which I call key and value. The key column is indexed, but not unique. Sometimes there is no or small amounts of values for a certain key, sometimes several hundreds.

For some reason, the following:

```
SELECT value FROM hashtable WHERE key = ?
```

has a very unstable speed! I could run my program (where the SELECT statement is used several thousands of times) and have a average time for every SELECT of 500 us, suddenly - without changing anything! - the next run it will have an average speed of 300 ms. The behaviour seems binary, or it's fast, or it's slow, it doesn't change within one run of my program and quite often when it turns into slow-mode I have to drop the index and rebuild it to make it fast again.

Anyone knows what could be the cause of this?

Thanks!

Comment: this can be caused by many things. Code is probably the last to check. Where it the database stored? Are you the only one accessing it? Is there anything else running on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have all the information you need: if performance is restored by rebuilding the index then the poor performance is likely due to index fragmentation due to updates, though you don't mention that you *are* updating it. Without changes to the database content I can't think of any reason why performance should change over time.

Comment: The only actions I'm doing on the database are:
create connection,
create cursor,
SELECTs (as explained before),
commit,
close connection.

Any of these could be the reason? It doesn't seem as if I'm changing anything in my database? (I commit because I've written a general class that also works for adding values, so closing and committing happens in the same method)

Comment: I can't imagine any of those operations would affect performance in the way you describe. SQLite was really designed for single use. Is it possible performance takes a nose-dive when a connection is left open? Stabbing in the dark here.